# JQuery Post-Request question - FF doesn't get the result of the referenced php page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I just want to have my question posted here but just from the beginning:
For a personal web project I use PHP + JQuery.

Now I got stuck when I try to use the ajax posting method to send data to another php-page. I planned to have some navigational elements like next + previous on the bottom of the page by saving the user input / user given data. The code looks as follows:

```
<div id="bottom_nav">
    <div id="prev" class="flt_l"><a href="?&step=<?= $pages[$step-1] ?>">next</a></div>
    <div id="next" class="flt_r"><a href="?&step=<?= $pages[$step+1] ?>">previous</a></div>
</div>
```

The functionality of the page works fine. Lateron, I use the following code to sent data over via POST:

```
$("#bottom_nav a").click( function() {
    alert("POST-Link: Parameter=" + $("#Parameter").val());
    $.ajax( {
        type:"post",
        url:"saveParameter.php",
        data:"Parameter=" + $("#Parameter").val(),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            //$("#test").text(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The request itself work perfectly on IE, but on FF I'm not able to get back any result.
within the PHP page, there just written:

```
<? echo $_POST['Parameter']; ?>
```

As IE returns the correct value, FF just provide an empty message box. I assumed that the behaviour on the -Link is different. While IE seems to handle the click event after the JS-Code execution, FF will interpret it before.

My question was whether you has a solution on this regarding restructuring the code itself or using another method to reach the intened behaviour.

Thanks for your assistance and recommendations,
Olli

Comment: Do you have Firebug installed and enabled in Firefox?  If so, can you use it to see what the response to your POST is?

Comment: As far as i understand Firebug, there's no response coming back.
The following POST command was sent:
Parameterapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
Parameter 80/Test/0/0/0/0/0/0
Quelle
ConfigCode=80%2FTest%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#bottom_nav a").click( function() {
  alert("POST-Link: Parameter=" + $("#Parameter").val());
  $.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveParameter.php",
    data: {
      Parameter: $("#Parameter").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      alert(result);
      //$("#test").text(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks cletus, but unfortunately this also won't work. Just tried it again... :(